# How to move the default google maps information window scrollbar to the right of the close button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, infowindow

When the scrollbar of an information window is shown, it displays to the left of the X button and takes up quite a bit of space to the right of the window's content. The scrollbar is displayed when adding the following CSS:

```
.mapInfoWindow {
    max-height:100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I would like to move the scrollbar to the right of the close button.

How can I do this?

I can't find any help with any of the above.

See the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/0g0ups7z/).

Comment: please define "custom scrollbar"

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the in InfoWindow content in DIV tags
CSS style the DIV tags with:

```
line-height:1.35;
overflow:hidden;
white-space:nowrap;
```

Both overflow:hidden and white-space:nowrap ensure no scrollbars are displayed. However, long text may spill outside of the InfoWindow.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: '<div style="line-height:1.35;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;">ADD CONTENT</div>'});
```

Hope This might help